# What does "NOLI" signify on a Cebu Air Pacific boarding pass?

Tags: tickets, terminology

What does "NOLI" signify on a Cebu Air Pacific boarding pass? It is printed alongside codes for a meal and baggage allowance.  We checked in at the terminal.

Comment: Did you check in online?  One usage was to indicate that the Terminal Tax (Airport Tax) has not been paid.

Comment: [It's latin for `don't!`.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nolo#Latin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOLI is used to indicate that the Terminal Tax has not been paid for flights.

I am not sure what the letters stand for.

Comment: Care to cite the reference you found? ;)

Comment: Personal experience.